# is method_setImplementation() atomic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime, method-swizzling

what will happened if `method_setImplementation()` is replacing `dealloc` method of NSObject class,and the same time in another thread, a NSObject instance is calling or is about to call `dealloc` method.

Will the instance  get the correct address of `dealloc` method?
I got random crash when I use method swizzling.And it's always crashed when it's calling dealloc method.

Here is my crash info:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000 at 0x0000000000000000
```

and the crashed thread:

```
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001837b7ffc 0x18379c000 + 114684 (__psynch_rw_unlock + 8)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183881b1c 0x183880000 + 6940 (pthread_rwlock_unlock + 380)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018328f718 0x18327c000 + 79640 (<redacted> + 20)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001832894a0 0x18327c000 + 54432 (method_setImplementation + 64)
4   MyApp                         0x0000000100904824 0x1000b4000 + 8718372 (kszombie_install + 204)
5   MyApp                         0x0000000100448248 0x1000b4000 + 3752520 (-[DYCrashReportManager configureAdvancedSettings] + 60)
6   MyApp                         0x000000010044756c 0x1000b4000 + 3749228 (+[DYCrashReportManager setDefaultKSCrashHander] + 100)
7   MyApp                         0x00000001000e15b4 0x1000b4000 + 185780 (-[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 700)
8   UIKit                           0x0000000188dde8a8 0x188d54000 + 567464 (<redacted> + 400)
9   UIKit                           0x000000018900e094 0x188d54000 + 2859156 (<redacted> + 2904)
10  UIKit                           0x0000000189012500 0x188d54000 + 2876672 (<redacted> + 1684)
11  UIKit                           0x000000018900f674 0x188d54000 + 2864756 (<redacted> + 168)
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001855bf7ac 0x185598000 + 161708 (<redacted> + 36)
13  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001855bf618 0x185598000 + 161304 (<redacted> + 168)
14  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001855bf9c8 0x185598000 + 162248 (<redacted> + 56)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183bd5124 0x183af4000 + 921892 (<redacted> + 24)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183bd4bb8 0x183af4000 + 920504 (<redacted> + 540)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183bd28b8 0x183af4000 + 911544 (<redacted> + 724)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183afcd10 0x183af4000 + 36112 (CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384)
19  UIKit                           0x0000000188dd7834 0x188d54000 + 538676 (<redacted> + 460)
20  UIKit                           0x0000000188dd1f70 0x188d54000 + 515952 (UIApplicationMain + 204)
21  DuoYiIM                         0x00000001000c4300 0x1000b4000 + 66304 (main + 132)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018369a8b8 0x183698000 + 10424 (<redacted> + 4)

Thread 2 Crashed:
0   (null) 0x0000000000000000 0x0 + 0
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183b01f14 0x183af4000 + 57108 (<redacted> + 148)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018329dae8 0x18327c000 + 137960 (<redacted> + 508)
3   Foundation                      0x00000001846dc844 0x184500000 + 1951812 (<redacted> + 1028)
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001838b4b4c 0x1838b0000 + 19276 (<redacted> + 28)
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001838b4af0 0x1838b0000 + 19184 (<redacted> + 40)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018366947c 0x183668000 + 5244 (<redacted> + 16)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001836754c0 0x183668000 + 54464 (<redacted> + 864)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018366cf80 0x183668000 + 20352 (<redacted> + 464)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018366947c 0x183668000 + 5244 (<redacted> + 16)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000183677914 0x183668000 + 63764 (<redacted> + 2140)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001836770b0 0x183668000 + 61616 (<redacted> + 112)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000183881470 0x183880000 + 5232 (_pthread_wqthread + 1092)
```

I got a null pointer.

Is there a safe way to replace dealloc method?

Comment: Redacting information in your stack trace about symbols in libobjc.dylib is not useful whatsoever. There's absolutely no way we can symbolicate these addresses into anything useful.

Comment: @ Richard J. Ross III.I use KSCrash to get my crash report.And I find every time it's crashed,there is a 'dealloc' string in x1 register.That means the system was calling dealloc method.The problem must be from  method swizzling,but I don't know the exact reason.I just doubt maybe method_setImplementation() is not atomic,so I came for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objc runtime manipulation methods are *generally* atomic, but atomicity does not mean thread safe.   Thread A screwing around with an object's implementation while thread B is using said object is always dangerous simply in that there is no guarantee whether thread B will use the new or old implementation.

Overall, though, **swizzling methods is bad and *swizzling NSObject's methods is worse***.

Comment: Is swizzling dealloc even well defined under ARC? I thought the compiler optimized away most of it when the class doesn't directly define it.

Comment: @RobNapier Yup;  I suspect mucking with dealloc via swizzling is likely digging the hole deeper under ARC, but I don't think it is flat out broken.   I.e. since basically any method can be called from cross-module boundaries, ARC must always be compatible with non-ARC and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find the reason of my crash.
That's because KSCrash swizzled `dealloc` method to detect zombie object.

```
static IMP g_originalDealloc_NSObject;
static void handleDealloc_NSObject(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    handleDealloc(self);
    typedef void (*fn)(id,SEL);
    fn f = (fn)g_originalDealloc_NSObject;
    f(self, _cmd);
}
static void installDealloc_NSObject()
{
    g_originalDealloc_NSObject = method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod([NSObject class], @selector(dealloc)),(IMP)handleDealloc_NSObject);
}
```

The crash happened when  in `installDealloc_NSObject()`,`method_setImplementation()` did change the implementation,but hadn't return the old implementation to `g_originalDealloc_NSObject` yet.And at the same moment in another thread, an object invoked `dealloc`,so in `handleDealloc_NSObject()` it got a null pointer error.